# Do we know if the ancient Jews embraced or refused the fourth century BCE observation of Aristotle that the Earth was a globe?

Tags: history, creation, genesis-bereishith

The Catholic Church fought long and hard for a fixed (stationary) earth, with the sky moving around it (a geocentric "universe"). Did it similarly take a long time for the Jews to accept the new cosmology of Aristotle?

> [Aristotle (384-322 BC) was among the first to recognize the fact of our planet being a round sphere.](https://www.eso.org/public/outreach/eduoff/seaspace/navigation/navastro/navastro-1.html#:%7E:text=Aristotle%20(384%2D322%20BC),general%20observations%20made%20at%20sea.) He observed lunar eclipses and noticed that only a round sphere could imply a circular shadow. This astronomical observation was confirmed by general observations made at sea.

NOTE: I only use the suppression of the heliocentric view (IE: Galileo) to provide a point of comparison. Some might find that choice as anti-Catholic or even historically untrue. Since it is simply there for comparison or contrasting, it doesn't matter if it is historically true. For the purposes of this discussion, let's assume or pretend that it is historical.

Comment: Could you add more detail and background to this question please?

Comment: ככדור - שהעולם עגול כדאיתא בירושלמי שאלכסנדרוס מוקדון עלה למעלה עד שראה כל העולם ככדור ואת הים כקערה פי' ים אוקינוס שמקיף את כל העולם:
Like a ball - That the world is round, as stated in the Jerusalem Talmud, that Alexander of Macedon ascended above until he saw all of the world like a ball, and the sea like a basin, meaning the great ocean that entirely encompasses the Earth.

https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Avodah_Zarah.41a.4.1

Comment: According to wikipedia on [Flat Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Earth): It is a historical myth that medieval Europeans generally thought the Earth was flat. This myth was created in the 17th century by Protestants to argue against Catholic teachings.

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: The quote from the Jerusalem Talmud is of significant interest to me. How sure are we that Alexander went high enough into space to see that the Earth is spherical, and not only far enough to observe that the horizon formed a circle? IE: round doesn't not equate to spherical.

Comment: Rabbi Kaii, I had no idea Catholic flat earth being a bit of Protestant propaganda. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Ruminator כדור = sphere

Comment: @ba Okay, thanks for providing the Hebrew.